Vibrate doesn't work when keyboard is being used
I am making a quiz with time limits in each question. When there is 10 seconds remaining, the device is supposed to vibrate in a specific pattern. For some reason, the vibration stops working in the following situations:

When the keyboard is being used, the vibration will not work at all, the keyboard will either not vibrate properly when pressing a key or will not vibrate at all. The device vibrates at random, uncontrolled moments. (as some questions require the use of a keyboard to answer questions)
When the back button (device) is being pressed, the vibration stops working (during the vibration phase).
(Unrelated to the above problems) At random moments, the phone vibrates at random intensity and duration, even though it isn't supposed to.
It also starts to vibrate when I switch apps (from my app to another app). If, however, when switching from another app to my app, the vibration completely stops.

Here is the code that I've written.
When initialising the vibrator
        val vibrationPatternsInstantiation = VibrationPatterns()

        val tenSecondsRemaningVibrator: Vibrator

        //initialising vibrator based on sdk versions
        tenSecondsRemaningVibrator = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
            val tenSecondsRemaningVibratorManager = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE) as VibratorManager
            tenSecondsRemaningVibratorManager.defaultVibrator
        } else{
            getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        }

Countdown timer in action
defaultCountdowntimer = object: CountDownTimer(questionTimerInMilliseconds, 1){
            override fun onTick(currentTimeInMilliseconds: Long){
                questionTimerProgressBar.progress = currentTimeInMilliseconds.toInt()
                setCountdowntimerToDifferentColours(currentTimeInMilliseconds)
                setVibrationWithTenSecondsLeft(currentTimeInMilliseconds)
                questionTimerInMilliseconds = currentTimeInMilliseconds
            }

            override fun onFinish(){
                onTick(0L)
                timeIsUp()
                setBooleanCheckAnswerButtonIsPressedToFalse()
                disableLifelineButton()
                disableAnswerButton()
                setAnswerButtonToWhite()
                disableConfirmAnswerButton()
            }
        }
    defaultCountdowntimer.start()

setVibrationWithTenSecondsLeft method/function
private fun setVibrationWithTenSecondsLeft(currentTimeInMilliseconds: Long){
        if(currentTimeInMilliseconds >= 10000){

            if(tenSecondsRemainingVibrator.hasVibrator()){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                    val effect = VibrationEffect.createWaveform(vibrationPatternsInstantiation.tenSecondsRemainingVibrationPattern, -1)
                    tenSecondsRemainingVibrator.vibrate(effect)
                } else {
                    val oldEffect = vibrationPatternsInstantiation.tenSecondsRemainingVibrationPattern
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    tenSecondsRemainingVibrator.vibrate(oldEffect, -1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

I have also added the following line into the AndroidManifest.xml file...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

Here is the VibrationPatterns class
class VibrationPatterns{

    //single player
    val singlePlayerCorrectAnswerVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 500)
    val singlePlayerWrongAnswerVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 1000)
    val singlePlayerTypeItIncorrectAnswerVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 125, 50, 125)

    //naming game
    val namingGameCorrectAnswerVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 250)
    val namingGameAlreadyAnsweredVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 125)
    val namingGameWrongAnswerVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 125, 50, 125)
    val namingGameGivenUpVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 750)

    val tenSecondsRemainingVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0,
        100, 900,
        100, 900,
        100, 900,
        100, 900,
        100, 900,
        125, 875,
        250, 750,
        500, 500,
        750, 250,
        1000, 0)

    val endOfGameVibrationPattern = longArrayOf(0, 500, 250, 500, 250, 750, 50, 250)
}


First, we do not know what VibrationPatterns is, as that is not part of the Android SDK. Second, we do not know when you are calling the code in your question. Third, we do not know whether the problem is that the 10-second vibration is interrupted by those situations (i.e., part-way through the 10 seconds, the situation causes the vibration to cease) or whether the vibration only won't start due to those situations (i.e., if it has started the 10 seconds, the vibration continues through those 10 seconds despite the situation).

Fourth, it is unclear if "It even starts to vibrate when I switch apps" means switching to your app from another app, switching from your app to another app, or both.

Updated the question. Apologies if I wasn't clear enough
